# Java Agent in Lotus Notes thrwoing "java.security.AccessControlException" Exception

Tags: java, lotus-notes, javaagents

I'm trying to use the Google Custom Search API to, obviously, search in google. I've made this Java Agent in Lotus Notes.

The Main Class:

```
import java.util.List;
import lotus.domino.AgentBase;
import com.google.api.services.customsearch.model.Result;
public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {
    public void NotesMain() {
        GoogleSearchClient gsc = new GoogleSearchClient();
        String searchKeyWord = "test";
        List<Result> resultList =    gsc.getSearchResult(searchKeyWord);
        if(resultList != null && resultList.size() > 0){
            for(Result result: resultList){
                System.out.println(result.getHtmlTitle());
                System.out.println(result.getFormattedUrl());
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And that's the GoogleSearchClient class:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.customsearch.Customsearch;
import com.google.api.services.customsearch.model.Result;
import com.google.api.services.customsearch.model.Search;
public class GoogleSearchClient {
    public List<Result> getSearchResult(String keyword){
        String GOOGLE_SEARCH_URL = https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?";
        //api key
        String API_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        //custom search engine ID
        String SEARCH_ENGINE_ID = "xxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxx";
        String FINAL_URL= GOOGLE_SEARCH_URL + "key=" + API_KEY + "&cx=" + SEARCH_ENGINE_ID;
        // Set up the HTTP transport and JSON factory
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory();
        //HttpRequestInitializer initializer = (HttpRequestInitializer)new CommonGoogleClientRequestInitializer(API_KEY);
        Customsearch customsearch = new Customsearch(httpTransport, jsonFactory,null);

        List<Result> resultList = Collections.emptyList();
        try {
            Customsearch.Cse.List list = customsearch.cse().list(keyword);
            list.setKey(API_KEY);
            list.setCx(SEARCH_ENGINE_ID);
            //num results per page
            //list.setNum(2L);

            //for pagination
            list.setStart(10L);
            Search results = list.execute();
            resultList = results.getItems();

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultList;
    }
}
```

I've got the code [here](http://weblog4j.com/2014/06/03/having-fun-with-google-custom-search-api-and-java/).

This returns me this Exception:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks)
    at java.security.AccessController.throwACE(AccessController.java:100)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:174)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:544)
    at COM.ibm.JEmpower.applet.AppletSecurity.superDotCheckPermission(AppletSecurity.java:1449)
    at COM.ibm.JEmpower.applet.AppletSecurity.checkPermission(AppletSecurity.java:1617)
    at COM.ibm.JEmpower.applet.AppletSecurity.checkPermission(AppletSecurity.java:1464)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:118)
    at com.google.api.client.util.FieldInfo.of(FieldInfo.java:97)
    at com.google.api.client.util.ClassInfo.<init>(ClassInfo.java:172)
    at com.google.api.client.util.ClassInfo.of(ClassInfo.java:90)
    at com.google.api.client.util.GenericData.<init>(GenericData.java:79)
    at com.google.api.client.util.GenericData.<init>(GenericData.java:61)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.<init>(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:109)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.<init>(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:57)
    at com.google.api.services.customsearch.CustomsearchRequest.<init>(CustomsearchRequest.java:43)
    at com.google.api.services.customsearch.Customsearch$Cse$List.<init>(Customsearch.java:178)
    at com.google.api.services.customsearch.Customsearch$Cse.list(Customsearch.java:154)
    at GoogleSearchClient.getSearchResult(Unknown Source)
    at JavaAgent.NotesMain(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've digged this Exception in the internet and I've understood that the JVM doesn't think that I have the privileges and tried some things.

1. I added this permissions below in the "Java.policy" archive in my local machine and in the server, but it doesn't work.

   ```
   grant { permission java.util.PropertyPermission "http.keepAlive", "read, write"; };
   grant { permission java.security.AllPermission; }
   ```
2. I would try [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21320200) but my Software Version is 9.
3. I tryed this same code in Eclipse and it worked just fine, so I think that's a Notes Security configuration that is wrong. I have to do in Lotus Notes because I have to save the informations in forms etc.
4. I changed the Runtime security Level to 3 (Allow restricted operations with full administration rights)

Any ideas that how can I go through this?

Answer (score 0):

When I was working on WS-Security for my Web Service Consumer in Lotus, I got the same error. I found out that I can avoid this by using [`AccessController.doPrivileged`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html#doPrivileged-java.security.PrivilegedAction-) method in my `.jar` file. So, you need to create separate `.jar` in your IDE and use it in your Lotus Agent.
Here is example of using `AccessController.doPrivileged` with your code:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.customsearch.Customsearch;
import com.google.api.services.customsearch.model.Result;
import com.google.api.services.customsearch.model.Search;
public class GoogleSearchClient {
    public List<Result> getSearchResult(final String keyword){
        String GOOGLE_SEARCH_URL = https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?";
        //api key
        final String API_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        //custom search engine ID
        final String SEARCH_ENGINE_ID = "xxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxx";
        String FINAL_URL= GOOGLE_SEARCH_URL + "key=" + API_KEY + "&cx=" + SEARCH_ENGINE_ID;
        // Set up the HTTP transport and JSON factory
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory();
        //HttpRequestInitializer initializer = (HttpRequestInitializer)new CommonGoogleClientRequestInitializer(API_KEY);
        final Customsearch customsearch = new Customsearch(httpTransport, jsonFactory,null);

        return AccessController.doPrivileged(
                new PrivilegedAction<List<Result>>() {
            @Override
            public List<Result> run() {
                List<Result> resultList = Collections.emptyList();
                try {
                    Customsearch.Cse.List list = customsearch.cse().list(keyword);
                    list.setKey(API_KEY);
                    list.setCx(SEARCH_ENGINE_ID);
                    //num results per page
                    //list.setNum(2L);

                    //for pagination
                    list.setStart(10L);
                    Search results = list.execute();
                    resultList = results.getItems();

                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return resultList;
            }
        });
    }
}
```